# Could not resolve the rosdep key 'catkin'

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Building packages on a local build farm (not my own packages, the same packages as in the official ROS distros),
yesterday everything worked fine, but today, all build jobs fail with:

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index http://mybuildfarm/rosdistro/index.yaml
Add distro "kinetic"
updated cache in /home/buildfarm/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
Crawling for packages in workspace '/tmp/ws/src'

[INFO ABOUT THE PACKAGE TO BUILD]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/devel/create_devel_task_generator.py", line 272, in resolve_names
   rosdep_key, view, installer, os_name, os_code_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/catkin_support.py", line 87, in resolve_for_os
    d = view.lookup(rosdep_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 197, in lookup
   return self.rosdep_defs[rosdep_name]
KeyError: 'catkin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/devel/create_devel_task_generator.py", line 288, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/devel/create_devel_task_generator.py", line 125, in main
    debian_pkg_names += resolve_names(['catkin'], **context)
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/devel/create_devel_task_generator.py", line 275, in resolve_names
    "Could not resolve the rosdep key '%s'" % rosdep_key)
RuntimeError: Could not resolve the rosdep key 'catkin'
```

It seems like the build cannot find catkin.

I tried clearing cashes and deleting and re-creating all jobs but the problem persists.

I checked the `prerequisites:` repository as specified in `index.yaml` which is `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/` and there were some changes last night, but I cannot tell if they are related.

Does anyone have a clue what could be causing this?

Thanks for your time!

Best regards,
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331683/could-not-resolve-the-rosdep-key-%27catkin%27/) by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2019-08-27**:
Is the rosdistro you're building locally also called `kinetic`? If you've called it something else then your buildfarm is likely trying to install `ros-$rosdistro-catkin` instead of `ros-kinetic-catkin`.

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2019-08-27**:
@nuclearsandwich Thank you for the comment!
I checked the job's xml files and they use as `--rosdistro-index-url` the correct server's index.yaml and the parameters `kinetic default <package> ubuntu xenial amd64`

In the index.yaml, the respective `distribution.yaml` is listed under the respective distributions' name, and the `distribution.yaml` is a copy of the official build farm's file.

EDIT:
I also inserted a print-out into the offending `create_devel_task_generator.py` and it prints out `kinetic` as `rosdistro_name` too, so I don't think the issue is a wrong rosdistro name.

Am I mistaken that the distro server is used to both decide which packages to build and also as the repository for required packages?

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2019-08-28**:
If your local rosdistro is still called kinetic, them my next suspect is that your kinetic/distribution.yaml is missing packages (for example, catkin). Did you edit the distribution.yaml in order to prune which packages you were building on your buildfarm deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @nuclearsandwich for pointing me to the source of the issue:
I wasn't aware even basic build tools like catkin need to be build first through distribution.yaml
(instead of being used from the `prerequisites:` repositories defined in the `ros_buildfarm_config`'s index.yaml.

`catkin` was actually also in the distribution list, but it failed to build for different reasons.

First it was `/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory` which I was able to work around by injecting `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` into the docker file,
then it failed because of not finding `python-catkin-pkg` or `ImportError: No module named terminal_color` so I injected installing python-catkin-pkg and python-catkin-pkg-modules as well.
Eventually I figured there's probably another package which is expected to be build first which would install all the packages and configure the build environment, so I tried building `ros` first. It also failed, but it apparently prepared the docker environment enough for `catkin` to build. Now, other packages build as well.

**tl;dr:**

`RuntimeError: Could not resolve the rosdep key` indicates that this package should be built first.

The correct order seems to be `cmake_modules` => `rospack` => `genmsg` => `roscpp_core` => `genpy` =>`message_runtime` => `ros` => `catkin` => all other packages.

---

Originally posted by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) with karma: 17 on 2019-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0